# What is the best way to migrate data in Cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, database-migration, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra cluster of 5 nodes with  `writeConsistency: LOCAL_QUORUM`. The cluster has TBs of Data. Now I need to migrate the data to a different `keyspace` in the same cluster. Following is the requirement.

```
keyspace_1 --> read data --> transform --> insert in keyspace_2.
```

Now we can do that by some multi-instance microservices, where we can read the data from `keyspace_1`, and then transform it and then insert it in the target keyspace.

But is there a better approach to it. I have found an article [How to migrate data from Cassandra cluster of size N to a different cluster of size N+/-M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781132/how-to-migrate-data-from-cassandra-cluster-of-size-n-to-a-different-cluster-of-s). But here mainly the SSTable is getting transferred without any transformation. But I need a data transformation mechanism in between. Can anyone suggest me a good approach here/ someone did this type of activity earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way will be to use Spark to load the data, perform transformations, and save data into new table(s) - as Spark is able to perform automatic parallelization of data processing, it will be easier than to use Spring Boot.  Depending on your requirements you can use either [Spark SQL API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md) or [RDD API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc) of the Spark Cassandra Connector.

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("keyspace" -> "ks", "table" -> "tab))
  .load

val dfTransformed = df.select.... // do transformation

dfTransformed.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("keyspace" -> "ks2", "table" -> "tab))
  .save
```

If you won't use Spark, then you'll need to perform full scan of all data, transform read data & write them - but this is more complicated task as you will need to handle failures, etc. Also, effective reading of the data from Cassandra not an easy task - you can look to this [code example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java), but I suggest to look to Spark first.